# Error while creating a catkin workspace

Tags: ros, python, catkin-make, catkin, anaconda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, ROS Indigo. I am getting the following catkin_make error, and I am not sure how to fix that -

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/ubuntu/dl_workspace/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/bin/python (found version "2.7.13") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/ubuntu/dl_workspace/build/test_results
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py", line 107, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py", line 99, in main
    package = parse_package(args.package_xml)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 317, in parse_package
    return parse_package_string(f.read(), filename)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 450, in parse_package_string
    raise InvalidPackage('Error(s) in %s:%s' % (filename, ''.join(['\n- %s' % e for e in errors])))
catkin_pkg.package.InvalidPackage: Invalid package manifest "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml": Error(s) in /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml:
- The manifest must not contain the following tags: depend, build_export_depend, buildtool_export_depend
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/bin/python
  "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/ubuntu/dl_workspace/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:63 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:151 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/dl_workspace/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/dl_workspace/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Kindly help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268903/error-while-creating-a-catkin-workspace/) by [robo_ninja](https://answers.ros.org/users/27502/robo_ninja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2017-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ros+anaconda+python+catkin_make+fail) found these answers:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/220546/catkin_make-failure-due-to-python-anaconda/?answer=220569#post-id-220569
- https://answers.ros.org/question/256886/conflict-anaconda-vs-ros-catking_pkg-not-found/?answer=256891#post-id-256891
- https://answers.ros.org/question/126471/cmake-failed-catkin_pkg/?answer=126486#post-id-126486
- https://answers.ros.org/question/172286/creating-ros-workspace-catkin_make-catkin_pkg-error/?answer=201154#post-id-201154
- https://answers.ros.org/question/215473/cmake-error-while-executing-catkin_make-on-ubuntu-1404-with-ros-jade/?answer=215512#post-id-215512

I'm aware with the fact that some of these are an error with `catkin_make`, but the common theme is that there is a conflict between Anaconda and the default Python path. You should try setting the default interpreter as your interpreter (2.7) instead of using Anaconda's.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robo_ninja](https://answers.ros.org/users/27502/robo_ninja/) on 2017-08-16**:
Thank you for your help. I removed Anaconda completely, and it works fine now.